# Local Noetherian ring and its invariants

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules, noetherian, invariant-theory

Let $R$ be a local Noetherian ring and $G$ a finite group. Is $R$ finitely generated as a module over its invariants $R^G$?

Thank you.